# Question about proof of Van Kampen theorem in Hatcher

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

The relevant chapter can be found here in the author's website: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf

The part I'm having trouble with is(it's page 45 in the book)

[image]

-The proof says that we may assume the s-partition subdivides the partitions giving the products $f_1..... f_k$ and $f_1'...... f'_l$.

Looking at this post: [Question about proof in Van Kampen's theorem; Hatcher](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453768/question-about-proof-in-van-kampens-theorem-hatcher), I'm not sure if I'm understanding this right, but it seems to mean that we can assume $s_0, .... s_m$ contains partition given by $f_1 .... f_k$. This isn't mentioned in the answer, but since the proof also says it subdivides the partition given by $f_1'....f_k'$, we must also insert the partition given by $f_1 ... f_k$?

-It says we may perturb the vertical sides. But how do we know this? Is is just since $A_\alpha$ is open, so we can move each block slightly? (that's not really formal, but that's my best guess)

-It also says that we may assume there are at least 3 rows? But how do we know this? Is it because if there are less than 3 rows, the proof becomes trivial somehow?

I know that's a lot, so sorry about that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the first one, it is an easy application of the so-called "tube lemma". For the second one, we may assume that $n>3$ by refining $0<t_0<\cdots<t_n<1$ if necessary, because what we really need is that each rectangle containing in some $F^{-1}(A_\alpha)$ (so refining is clearly has no problem). It doesn't mean that the proof is trivial when $n\leq 2$. By the way, note that the existence of partitions $\{s_i\}$ and $\{t_j\}$ are a consequence of the Lebesgue number lemma.